# Building a Hash Table to store customer names - Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Build a system that allows a sales associate to enter a customer's name, 
 address, and phone number into the system and look up customers using their 
 phone numbers.
 Store this information in a hash table.

```
const hashTable = () => {
   this.customer = name;
   this.address  = address;
   this.number   = number;
}
```

I guess I'm not understanding hash tables, they're similar to objects but they can hold any data type?

Comment: generally, hash tables and objects are terms that are used interchangeably. 
What is happening in the code sample above is that functions are technically objects in JS. so you can assign properties to them just like you would in an object

Comment: So I would just write the functions as if i'm using objects?

Comment: Is the code above yours? Or were you given it and now you're trying to understand what's going on there?

Comment: It's mine, this is what I believe they're asking for, at least to start off.

Comment: well I would not use a function as an object unless you need it to be a function (rare case). Just stick to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have customer data stored in objects like following :

```
customerData = {
  customer : 'John Smith',
  address : '1 Way ...',
  number : '0604....',
}
```

If you just want a simple way to store customers and lookup for a customer with his number, you can just use an object :

```
const hashTable = {}

const addCustomer = customerData => {
  hashTable[customerData.number] = customerData
}

const searchCustomer = customerNumber => {
  return hashTable[customerNumber]
}

const removeCustomer = customerNumber => {
  hashTable[customerNumber] = null
}
```

The resulting Object will be something like :

```
hashTable = {
  '0604....' : {
    customer : 'John Smith',
    address : '1 Way ...',
    number : '0604....',
  },
  '0702....' : {
    customer : 'Michel Doe',
    address : '2 Street ...',
    number : '0702....',
  },
}
```

Trade-off here are :

- You can't have multiples customers with the same number, `hashTable[customerNumber]` can only "hold" one reference of customer. But why two customers would have the same number...
- Maybe you don't want a redundancy of the number : with this implementation, the number is the key, and is also stored in each reference of customer data. Btw it's a minor issue if you don't have hundred of thousands of customers.
- Others very minor performance and memory issues if again you work with hundred of thousands of customers

Comment: ah ok, thanks for that, ill take a look at it and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when people are talking about a hash table, they are talking about looking things up. The great thing about a hash table is that you look things up by the key, so lookups are O(1).

So for your example, we want a hash table full of customer objects. The expected output should look something like:

```
customer_list = {
  "(123) 456-7890": {
    "name": "Fred Jones",
    "email": "fred@email.com",
    "phone": "(123) 456-7890"
  },
  "(223) 456-7890": {
    "name": "John James",
    "email": "john@email.com",
    "phone": "(223) 456-7890"
  },
  "(323) 456-7890": {
    "name": "Jim Bob",
    "email": "jim@email.com",
    "phone": "(323) 456-7890"
  }
}
```

So we can look up Jim Bob by their phone number using `customer_list["(323) 456-7890"]` and get:

```
{
  "name": "Jim Bob",
  "email": "jim@email.com",
  "phone": "(323) 456-7890"
}
```

Now, to make things a bit easier, we can make a `Customer` class that will handle the creation of the customer objects and handle invalid data, and we can extend `Map` implementing `Map#set` such that we make sure that the element being set is an instance of `Customer`

```js
class Customer {
  constructor({ name = "", email = "", phone = "" }) {
    if (name !== "" || email !== "" || phone !== "") {
      this.name = name
      this.email = email
      this.phone = phone
    } else {
      throw new Error('All fields must be filled')
    }
  }
}

class CustomerList extends Map {
  add(customer) {
    if(customer instanceof Customer) {
      return super.set(customer.phone, customer)
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('Argument `customer` must be a instance of Customer')
    }
  }
  set(phone, customer) {
    if(customer instanceof Customer) {
      return super.set(phone, customer)
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('Argument `customer` must be a instance of Customer')
    }
  }
}

const customer_list = new CustomerList()

const customer_inputs = [
  { 
    name: 'Fred Jones',
    email: 'fred@email.com',
    phone: '(123) 456-7890'
  },
  { 
    name: 'John James',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    phone: '(223) 456-7890'
  },
  { 
    name: 'Jim Bob',
    email: 'jim@email.com',
    phone: '(323) 456-7890'
  }
]

for(let input of customer_inputs) {
  const customer = new Customer(input)
  customer_list.add(customer)
}

function handleCustomerInputSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = new FormData(event.target)
  const hash = {}
  for(let key of data.keys()) hash[key] = data.get(key)
  try {
    const customer = new Customer(hash)
    customer_list.add(customer)
    alert('Added Customer')
    event.target.reset()
  } catch(error) {
    alert(error)
  }
}

let output_element = null

function handleCustomerSearchSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = new FormData(event.target)
  const phone = data.get('phone')
  const customer = customer_list.get(phone)
  if(customer) {
    output_element.innerHTML = `
      <label>
          <span class="label-text">Name:</span>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="${ customer.name }" readonly>
      </label>
      <label>
          <span class="label-text">Email:</span>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="${ customer.email }" readonly>
      </label>
      <label>
          <span class="label-text">Phone:</span>
          <input type="text" name="phone" value="${ customer.phone }" readonly>
      </label>
    `
  } else {
    output_element.innerHTML = `
      <div class="error">No customer found</div>
    ` 
  }
}

function handleDOMLoad(event) {
  const forms = {}
  
  const customer_input = document.querySelector('#customer-input')
  customer_input.addEventListener('submit', handleCustomerInputSubmit, true)
  
  const customer_search = document.querySelector('#customer-search')
  customer_search.addEventListener('submit', handleCustomerSearchSubmit, true)
  
  output_element = customer_search.querySelector('.output')
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleDOMLoad)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

form#customer-input,
form#customer-search {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}
form#customer-input label,
form#customer-search label {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}
form#customer-input label span.label-text,
form#customer-search label span.label-text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
form#customer-input label input,
form#customer-search label input {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
form#customer-input > button,
form#customer-search > button {
  margin: 5px;
}

form#customer-search .output .error {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="customer-input">
  <h1>Create Customer</h1>
  <label>
      <span class="label-text">Name:</span>
      <input type="text" name="name">
  </label>
  <label>
      <span class="label-text">Email:</span>
      <input type="text" name="email">
  </label>
  <label>
      <span class="label-text">Phone:</span>
      <input type="text" name="phone">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Create Customer</button>
</form>
<form id="customer-search">
  <h1>Find Customer</h1>
  <label>
      <span class="label-text">Phone:</span>
      <input type="text" name="phone">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Find Customer</button>
  <div class="output"></div>
</form>
```